# Laravel 5.8 - Validate future date

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

How do I validate that a given date is in the future and not a past date?  Alternatively, does Html 5 allows one to disable past date from a date field?

I have a form in my app that allows user to select start date for an event from an HTML date input field. I want users to only choose a date in the future and not a past date.

Comment: Everything you need to know about the HTML 5 `date` input type can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date specifically the `min` property. You're unclear if you want server or client side validation.

Comment: This was helpful for front-end validation. it worked for me like so:  ```<input type="date" min="{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Carbon\Carbon::now() ))   }}"   name="event_date" id="event_date"   > ```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use it like this:

```
$rules = [
    'start_date' => 'date_format:d/m/Y|after:3/13/2019',
];
```

See also the `laravel` documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-after
or
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-after-or-equal

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I want. I have edited my question.

Comment: `after:3/13/2019` why hardcode the date? `after:today` (or similar) should be used for any future dates.

Answer (score 1):

`after:today` works as @Tim Lewis commented above.

As for HTML validation, date fields still aren't fully supported. Safari being the main culprit.

You can use `min="2020-01-01"` format against the input, but you'll need to either add that date server-side or using JavaScript so it's tomorrow's date.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried code and found that if you want to validate only year than you can write something like

```
$rules = ['dob'=>'required|date_format:Y|before:today']
```

where,
`date_format`
is fixed keyword and with help of `'Y'` you can validate only year

and `before:today` validate if year is older than today or not.

you can use `d-m-Y` format instead only `Y`.

happy coding...